# How can I populate a collection with its sub collections in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPcVf.png)

How can I populate books with their chapters by mongoose query?

**note:** *Chapter contains the ref object of their books but books doesn't.*

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ This should help

Comment: @Anveeg Sinha, Thank you!! I got it..